# Setting color of specific row in table if the value inside is >1000

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So like in the title i want to click the button set row to green if value inside is higher than 1000 i think i figured out the part with setting color im not sure about the button part here is
the specific part of code also the jsfiddle

```
$('.netto').filter(function makeGreen () {
    return parseInt($.trim($(this).text()), 10) > 1000
}).closest('td').css('background-color', '#24AD36');
```

```js
$(function() {
  var vat = [{
      display: "ZW",
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      display: "NP",
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      display: "0%",
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      display: "3%",
      value: "3",
    },
    {
      display: "8%",
      value: "8",
    },
    {
      display: "23%",
      value: "23",
    },
  ];

  var options = ['<option value="">Wybierz VAT</option>'];

  for (var i = 0; i < vat.length; i++) {
    options.push('<option value="');
    options.push(vat[i].value);
    options.push('">');
    options.push(vat[i].display);
    options.push("</option>");
  }

  $(".obliczvat")
    .html(options.join(""))
    .change(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val == 0) {
        var ilosc = parseInt($(this).closest("td").prev().text(), 10);
        var brutto = parseInt($(this).closest("td").next().text(), 10);

        var ob = brutto * ilosc;
        $(this).closest("td").next().next().text(ob);
      }
      if (val == 3) {
        var ilosc = parseInt($(this).closest("td").prev().text(), 10);
        var brutto = parseInt($(this).closest("td").next().text(), 10);

        var ob = (brutto * ilosc) - brutto * ilosc * 0.03;

        $(this).closest("td").next().next().text(ob);
      }
      if (val == 8) {
        var ilosc = parseInt($(this).closest("td").prev().text(), 10);
        var brutto = parseInt($(this).closest("td").next().text(), 10);

        var ob = (brutto * ilosc) - brutto * ilosc * 0.08;

        $(this).closest("td").next().next().text(ob);
      }
      if (val == 23) {
        var ilosc = parseInt($(this).closest("td").prev().text(), 10);
        var brutto = parseInt($(this).closest("td").next().text(), 10);

        var ob = (brutto * ilosc) - brutto * ilosc * 0.23;

        $(this).closest("td").next().next().text(ob);
      }
    });
  $(function() {

    $('.tabela tbody tr').each(function() {
      var bruttoW = $('.bruttow', this).text();

      var ilosc = parseInt($('.ilosc', this).text(), 10);
      var brutto = parseInt($('.brutto', this).text(), 10);


      var ob = (brutto * ilosc);
      $('.bruttow', this).text(ob);


    });
  })


});



$('.netto').filter(function makeGreen() {
  return parseInt($.trim($(this).text()), 10) > 1000
}).closest('td').css('background-color', '#24AD36');
```

```css
body {
  background: #34568B;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tabela">
  <tr>
    <th>Lp.</th>
    <th>Opis</th>
    <th>Ilość</th>
    <th>VAT</th>
    <th>Kwota Brutto</th>
    <th>Wartość Netto</th>
    <th>Wartość Brutto</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Palety</td>
    <td class="ilosc">2</td>
    <td>
      <form name="Vat">
        <select class="obliczvat"></select>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="brutto">2000zł</td>
    <td class="netto"></td>
    <td class="bruttow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Modernizjacja sprzętu komputerowego</td>
    <td class="ilosc">8</td>
    <td>
      <form name="Vat">
        <select class="obliczvat"></select>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="brutto">120zł</td>
    <td class="netto"></td>
    <td class="bruttow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>modernizacja biura</td>
    <td class="ilosc">4</td>
    <td>
      <form name="Vat">
        <select class="obliczvat"></select>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="brutto">5007zł</td>
    <td class="netto"></td>
    <td class="bruttow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Paliwo</td>
    <td class="ilosc">7</td>
    <td>
      <form name="Vat">
        <select class="obliczvat"></select>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="brutto">359zł</td>
    <td class="netto"></td>
    <td class="bruttow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Zakup nowego Samochódu do floty</td>
    <td class="ilosc">1</td>
    <td>
      <form name="Vat">
        <select class="obliczvat"></select>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="brutto">23755zł</td>
    <td class="netto"></td>
    <td class="bruttow"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" name="green" onclick="makeGreen()">button</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ramfwt31/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically had it, but the inline onclick was throwing it off so I added a jquery click and an id for your button so the function is called when the button is clicked

```js
$(function() {
  var vat = [{
      display: "ZW",
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      display: "NP",
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      display: "0%",
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      display: "3%",
      value: "3",
    },
    {
      display: "8%",
      value: "8",
    },
    {
      display: "23%",
      value: "23",
    },
  ];

  var options = ['<option value="">Wybierz VAT</option>'];

  for (var i = 0; i < vat.length; i++) {
    options.push('<option value="');
    options.push(vat[i].value);
    options.push('">');
    options.push(vat[i].display);
    options.push("</option>");
  }

  $(".obliczvat")
    .html(options.join(""))
    .change(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val == 0) {
        var ilosc = parseInt($(this).closest("td").prev().text(), 10);
        var brutto = parseInt($(this).closest("td").next().text(), 10);

        var ob = brutto * ilosc;
        $(this).closest("td").next().next().text(ob);
      }
      if (val == 3) {
        var ilosc = parseInt($(this).closest("td").prev().text(), 10);
        var brutto = parseInt($(this).closest("td").next().text(), 10);

        var ob = (brutto * ilosc) - brutto * ilosc * 0.03;

        $(this).closest("td").next().next().text(ob);
      }
      if (val == 8) {
        var ilosc = parseInt($(this).closest("td").prev().text(), 10);
        var brutto = parseInt($(this).closest("td").next().text(), 10);

        var ob = (brutto * ilosc) - brutto * ilosc * 0.08;

        $(this).closest("td").next().next().text(ob);
      }
      if (val == 23) {
        var ilosc = parseInt($(this).closest("td").prev().text(), 10);
        var brutto = parseInt($(this).closest("td").next().text(), 10);

        var ob = (brutto * ilosc) - brutto * ilosc * 0.23;

        $(this).closest("td").next().next().text(ob);
      }
    });
  $(function() {

    $('.tabela tbody tr').each(function() {
      var bruttoW = $('.bruttow', this).text();

      var ilosc = parseInt($('.ilosc', this).text(), 10);
      var brutto = parseInt($('.brutto', this).text(), 10);


      var ob = (brutto * ilosc);
      $('.bruttow', this).text(ob);


    });
  })


});

$('#green').on('click', function(event) {
  $('.netto').filter(function makeGreen() {
    return parseInt($.trim($(this).text()), 10) > 1000;
  }).closest('td').css('background-color', '#24AD36');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #34568B;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tabela">
  <tr>
    <th>Lp.</th>
    <th>Opis</th>
    <th>Ilość</th>
    <th>VAT</th>
    <th>Kwota Brutto</th>
    <th>Wartość Netto</th>
    <th>Wartość Brutto</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Palety</td>
    <td class="ilosc">2</td>
    <td>
      <form name="Vat">
        <select class="obliczvat"></select>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="brutto">2000zł</td>
    <td class="netto"></td>
    <td class="bruttow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Modernizjacja sprzętu komputerowego</td>
    <td class="ilosc">8</td>
    <td>
      <form name="Vat">
        <select class="obliczvat"></select>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="brutto">120zł</td>
    <td class="netto"></td>
    <td class="bruttow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>modernizacja biura</td>
    <td class="ilosc">4</td>
    <td>
      <form name="Vat">
        <select class="obliczvat"></select>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="brutto">5007zł</td>
    <td class="netto"></td>
    <td class="bruttow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Paliwo</td>
    <td class="ilosc">7</td>
    <td>
      <form name="Vat">
        <select class="obliczvat"></select>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="brutto">359zł</td>
    <td class="netto"></td>
    <td class="bruttow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Zakup nowego Samochódu do floty</td>
    <td class="ilosc">1</td>
    <td>
      <form name="Vat">
        <select class="obliczvat"></select>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="brutto">23755zł</td>
    <td class="netto"></td>
    <td class="bruttow"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="green" name="green">button</button>
```

Comment: yeah i felt that something was off i have one more question tho if the table has bg set in css do i need to do some changes still?

Comment: Not unless you have a specific need to. The attribute is being set in the HTML if you inspect the code in your browser and try your function. You don't really need to apply more CSS if this was the end goal.

Comment: yeah i kind of have because the whole table color is set to white i forgot to add in jsfidlle

Comment: @smoken122 it won't change the outcome of your function. The JQ will overwrite any color your set in the CSS because it's being applied directly to your HTML on call, so you're all good :)

Comment: yeah it shouldn't but it does i uploaded my whole html and css to jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/gr1524dh/ and still won't work

Comment: @smoken122 I’m on my phone right now and jsfiddle isn’t mobile friendly but if I had to guess I think it’s because you have your scripts loaded into the html section and not the scripts section of the editor. If you do have issues with it you could wrap the entire table in a container and just set the background color of the container instead of messing with the table.

Comment: i fixed it i just needed to add the script to the bottom of my html so it loads last than it works jsfidlle does the same thanks a lot for help